# Hover doesn't react

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

My hover doesn't work at all. I need my element to only show up when I hover over it, but I can't get it to work.

I don't know if it's necessary to replace the `i` tag with an `a`, or if the error is in the css. I also tried with `display: none` and `display: block`, but the problem still doesn't solve. What can it be?

My html:

```
                        <div class="vertical-line"></div>
                        <div>
                            <h4>{{ banner.textPrimary }}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h2>{{ banner.textSecondary }}<br /></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vertical-line"></div>

                        <div>
                            <a href="{{ banner.buttonLink }}" target="_blank">
                                <button
                                    [style.background-color]="banner.buttonColor"
                                    style="border: solid 1px"
                                    class="btn-about-us"
                                    mat-raised-button
                                    color="primary"
                                >
                                    {{ banner.buttonText }}
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <i
                    (click)="openBannerDeleteModal(banner.uuid)"
                    *ngIf="isAdminFlag === 'true'"
                    class="fas fa-trash-alt delete-modal"
                    id="banner-delete"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                ></i>
```

And my css:

```
.delete-modal{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 80%;
    left: 91%;
    z-index: 1000;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.delete-modal:hover{
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: @AlbertoCasasOrtiz Please do not translate questions on behalf of other users. The translation should be done by the user themself, see this [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680).

Answer (score 2):

For `visibility: hidden;` hover does not work and it is a normal behavior. 
I think in your case `opacity` would be better.

```
.delete-modal {
  ...
  opacity: 0;
}

.delete-modal:hover {
  ...
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant hover over something is not visible on your page, in that way your hover event is not fired at all,

instead place the hover on the parent, then do visibilty:visible on the desired element.